# How to match prefixes in a comma-separated list?

Tags: mysql

I have a `Store` table containing a `deliveryPostcodes` field, which is a comma-separated list of postcode areas:

```
id    deliveryPostcodes
1     EC1,EC2,N1
2     EC1,WC1,WC2
3     N1,N2
```

I'd like to query this table for stores matching a postcode, for example if the user enters `EC2A 9XY`, it should return the first row, as this one has an entry in the list that is a prefix of the full postcode.

**Is there a solution to do that without a custom function?**

Note: I know I could do this by joining a separate table with one postcode area per line, but I'm exploring the different options for now.

Comment: your DB looks shabby. Start think to change it soon

Comment: The trick is to never ever use comma separated lists. Read up about database normalization.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, I expected them as you can see in my footer note. Still curious to explore the different solutions.

Comment: this is not an OPTION

Comment: @Strawberry LoL, noted!

Comment: @Benjamin Please, I will pay you to normalize this table.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I'll email my bank details right now ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer, but the only correct solution for this problem: normalize the data and put it inside a separate table. Since your solution is:

1. bad for indexing
2. bad for searching
3. solving this with regex will have a massive performance hit
4. this kind of structure will cause problems once your database starts to grow.

A lookup table with postcodes may also come in handy later on. A list of the postcodes of the country (or contries) you want, can easily be found on google, possibly even in a format that you can import in MySQL with minimal work.

Comment: Actually I think *this* is the answer, even though I did not want to consider it at first because I wanted to focus, out of interest, on the comma-separated solution. But everybody's reaction made me understand that there's no debate!

Comment: When you work on a large project that does not have a decent normalized database structure, you will understand why it is important :) Although denormalization may sometimes be benificial for performance reasons! Nothing is black-and-white...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming DeliveryPostcodes are numeric values, You can try using regular expression matching like this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Store
WHERE deliveryPostcodes RLIKE '.*,?[0-9]+,?.*'
```

Comment: But what would I put in the `RLIKE`? I would have to figure out all the different combinations of prefixes and execute it on `W`, `WC`, `WC2`, ... Plus, if the item is first or last in the list, there won't be any commas on one side, so the regexp will fail!

Comment: `.*,?` at the beginning of the regex should match zero or more characters followed by zero or one commas. Similarly `,?.*` sequence at the end to match zero or one comma, followed by zero or more characters

Comment: You're right indeed. But it will also match pretty much **any** string: you could very well remove the `,?` and the result would be the same.

Comment: right. The regex example is in no way the one you want to use as-is. Since you have not shared any sample data, this is the best I can make...  You need to suitably modify it to enforce more stricter match based on your data, such as length of `deliveryPostcodes`. Having those commas is just to highlight this aspect.

Comment: My mistake. I somehow assumes Post codes are numeric. In that case `RLIKE` is an overkill. you can use `LIKE` with wildcard matching. But your choice to normalize the table is good too. However, with recent versions of mysql and postgre sql supporting `JSON` and `full text search` natively, that thinking may change.